# A little clarification in the definition of graph product.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I was going through some graph products. Link  : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_product.

There is a not so famous product named as *co-normal product* and is defined for two graphs only. It states that if $G$ is a co-normal product of any two graphs then any two vertices $(u_1,u_2)$ and $(v_1,v_2)$ are adjacent if $u1 ∼ v1$ or $u2 ∼ v2 $.

I tried to extend for $n$ graphs as and defined adjacency as:

Any  two distinct vertices $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $y = (y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ are adjacent
as long as $x_i \sim y_i$ for some $i\in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

I want to know does it mean that for two vertices $x$ and $y$ to be adjacent, we must have $x_i\sim y_i$ for exactly  one $i\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$?

Can I make $x$ and $y$ adjacent if $x_i\sim y_i$ and $x_j\sim y_j$ in $G_i$ and $G_j$, resp., where $i\neq j$. Kindly help.

My thoughts : I think I can not do that otherwise that will be the definition of strong product of graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the "or" in "$u_1 \sim v_1$ or $u_2 \sim v_2$" is an inclusive or. That is, you also connect $(u_1,v_1)$ with $(u_2,v_2)$ if *both* $u_1$ is connected to $v_1$ and $u_2$ is connected to $v_2$.

Hence, "morally correct" definition is that you should let $x,y$ be connected if there is *at least* one $i$ such that $x_i$ and $y_i$ are connected in the $i$th graph. If $G$ is the conormal product of $G_1,\ldots,G_n$, and we write $+$ for the binary conormal product, then we want to have
$$
G = (\cdots ((G_1 + G_2) + G_3) + \cdots + G_n),
$$
and this works only for that definition.